# python-skeleton-autoinsert always set for certain files

Tags: python, emacs

I've been using Emacs 23 for a long time, and recently upgraded to Emacs 24 on my OSX laptop. One of the changes in Emacs 24 is the `python-skeleton-autoinsert` . . . it sets a little wizard when you are in a Python mode so when you type `if<space>` a prompt comes up in the mini-buffer. I find this highly annoying so I sought to shut it off.

When I upgraded `emacs-for-python`, it did . . . mostly. But files in my `virtualenv` still act like `python-skeleton-autoinsert` is still set. When I create or edit a file outside of my virtualenv directory, it acts like it isn't set.

I do use `desktop-save` and `ido` but deleting those files don't seem to effect this.

What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like your virtualenv directory contains a [`.dir-locals.el`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) which includes something like `(setq python-skeleton-autoinsert t)`.

Comment: Aaron: I thought about that, but I've never used that functionality. I did a search for .dir-locals.el and didn't find one in my entire home directory. Also did a search for `python-skeleton-autoinsert` in all my VirtualEnvs and didn't find anything.

Comment: How about in your Emacs init files? It's got to be somewhere...